# Как создать custom button?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать такую кнопку, с треугольником?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143905/android-make-an-arrow-shape-with-xml)
и [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396194/creating-a-triangular-shaped-button-for-android-application)
ответы на стеке, и из того, что есть, меняйте как вам нужно.

Answer (score -3):

```
.popup-top-corner {
 background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-top: 3px solid rgb(145, 27, 54);
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 300px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
 }

.popup-top-corner:before {
 content: '';
 border: 12px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 12px solid rgb(145, 27, 54);
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -12px;
 top: -27px;
 width: 0;
}
```

вот так сказать исходник, сделайте под себя просто

Comment: Это давно в андроиде так можно?